# Connect to Hololens via WLAN

Tags: wifi, hololens

I am trying to connect to my Hololens 2 with a web browser. I can see the IP address of the Hololens in my router interface, or when I ask "What is my IP address?" the Hololens comes back with the same one (192.168.178.70). But when I enter that in a web browser, it doesn't connect. I have played around with a lot of options now, but I can't get it to work. I also saw there is a local area connection 1 and 2 ("View hardware and connection properties"), but they are "Not operational". What do I do with those?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the device portal button in the developers section was still turned off. After turning it on, I could connect. I am pretty sure that I had turned it on before. Does it turn off automatically under certain circumstances?

Comment: I've noticed that after an update the device portal button in the developers section was reset, thus leading me into the same problem you had.